# How can I open a new webpage when user clicks on a category using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Home />
      <App />
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App.js  for all ROUTES in the app

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/cpu" exact component={Info}/>   
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Navs function in Home.class

```js
function Navs(){
  return(
    ReactDOM.render(
      <div className="Navs">
        <ul>
          <Router>
            <Link to="/cpu">CPU</Link>
            <Link to="/Monitors">MONITORS</Link>
            <Link to="/GPU">GPUS</Link>
            <Link to="/Ram">RAMS</Link>
            <Link to="/Keyboards">KEYBOARDS</Link>
            <Link to="/Mouse">MOUSE </Link> 
            <Link to="/Others">OTHER ACCESORIES</Link>
          </Router>
        </ul>
      </div>
      ,document.getElementById('Navs')
    )
  )
}
```

CPU.jsx(The component tobe rendered when user clicks on cpu category

```js
function Info(){
  render(
    <h1>Hello in cpus </h1>
  )
  return null
}
```

The problem is when I Navigate on cpu  it shows the same Home page but with the cpu component rendered in it..But the path is changed to "http://localhost:3000/cpu"

Comment: You put the `<Router>` inside `<App>` which is a sibling of `<Home>` so that home will always get rendered. Set up a `<Route>` for home instead and don't render `<Home>` beside <App>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your index.js you are including `<Home />` and then `<App />`.
For not showing Home you should include it into App as another route.
Eg.:

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
      <App />
      </div>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

App:

```
function App() {
        return(
    <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/cpu" exact component={Info}/> 
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/> 
    </Switch>
    </Router>
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

your program is working correctly. Your `ReactDOM.render` always renders `Home` and `App`. But `App` is empty in root directory. If you click on the route `/cpu` the `Info` Component will shown inside the `App` component. `Home` remains unaffected.

I would take `Home` out of `ReactDOM.render` and assign a route in the `App` Component for it. but don't forget to assign `exact path` for the `Home` route, otherwise you still have the same result ;-)

This will help you:
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start